# Finding Highest Product of Numbers Using Array

Tags: arrays, swift, function, numbers

I am writing a function that will return the highest product of two numbers in an array, so far my function can return the highest number in arrays that have only positive numbers or only negative numbers. How can i write my function where it will know that the two negative numbers might have a larger product than the two highest numbers I.E. -20 * -20 is larger than 2 * 3. I tried writing a if statement to see if that fixed it but it didn't. Can someone please direct me on how I cold fix my code to accomodate this?

```
func adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: [Int]) -> Int {
var array2 = inputArray.sorted(by: { $0 > $1})
var array3 = inputArray.sorted(by: { $0 < $1})

// Lowest
let firstLow = array3[0]    
let secondLow = array3[1]

// Highest
let firstMax = array2[0]
let secondMax = array2[1]

// Trying to fix the problem
if firstLow * secondLow > firstMax * secondMax {
    return firstLow * secondLow 
} else {
    return firstMax * secondMax
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be much more efficient and easier to enumerate all elements and multiply them

```
var result = Int.min
for i in (0..<array.count) {
    for j in (i+1..<array.count) {
         result = max(max, array[i] * array[j])
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is a nested loop (O(n^2)) more efficient than sorting (O(n log(n))) ?

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a pretty tricky scenario, depending on how strict you want to be with the outcome, because of all the edge cases. You can have the following scenarios:

- Only 1 positive number
- Only 1 negative number
- Only 1 negative and 1 positive number
- 1 positive, 1 negative and `0`
- No numbers

Here is my simple solution, which should cover everything.

```
func adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: [Int]) -> Int {
    let sorted = inputArray.sorted()
    let count = sorted.count
    if count > 1 {
        return max(sorted[0] * sorted[1], sorted[count - 1] * sorted[count - 2])
    } else {
        return sorted.first ?? 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't work for example [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]

Comment: That doesn't give you 42? (I'm pretty sure that's the ultimate answer :p)